# Instantiating class by generic parameter - which method is better

Tags: java, generics, parameters, instantiation

I have many html forms referring to many persistence classes.

All the html forms are generated by one single class HTMLForm by passing in the respective HTMLFields instances:

```
public class HTMLForm<T>{
 HTMLForm(HTMLFields[] f, Class<T> classt){
  this.stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance = classt;

  // ... whatever GWT jazz ....
 }

 public T getPersistenceHandlerClass(){
   try{
     return (T) stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance.newInstance();
   }
   catch (InstantiationException e){}
   catch (IllegalAccessException e){}
 }

 Class<T> stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance;
}
```

HTMLForm looks at HTMLFields[] array to generate the respective html forms. Therefore, each set of HTMLFields[] array require a different persistence class. The persistence classes are like

```
PostalAddr, PersonInfo, ItemDescr, Preferences, etc, etc.
```

Now since I cannot do T.newInstance(), *stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance* would be assigned (a silly necessity due to sun's architecture of generics) by the HTMLForm constructor and then *getPersistenceHandlerClass* is used later to get the appropriate persistence handling class.

Since cloud computing charges by the cpu hour, my question is, which would use less cpu, presuming I have about 25 persistence classes to wade thro. The first one above or the one following?

```
 public T getPersistenceHandlerClass(){
  if (stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance == PostalAddress.class)
    return new PostalAddress();
  if (stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance == PersonInfo.class)
    return new PersonInfo();

  if (stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance == ....
    ....
    ....

  if (stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance == etc.class)
    return new etc();
 }
```

or a Map of factories

```
 public static Map<PersistenceHandlerFactoryInterface> PHFactories;
 public T getPersistenceHandlerClass(){
  return
   PHFactories.get(stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance).createInstance();
 }
```

or make a better suggestion (with cpu consumption consideration) on how I should overcome java generics shortcoming, for another way to instantiate from parameter T. (*Or critique me why I'm being too heady criticising sun's generic parametric shortcoming*).

Comment: criticizing java generics is a common sport nowadays, so don't expect critique on that one :)

Comment: Criticising Java generics is fine, but I suggest you'd be better off doing it in a more thoughtful and less provocative way.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but as you have a `Class` instance to work with, wouldn't `stupidSunWontAllowTnewInstance.newInstance()` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the first form - I *very* much doubt that any performance difference is going to be significant. If you're really worried about it though, *measure* the difference.

Another alternative is to use an enum:

```
public enum PersistenceHandlerFactory
{
    POSTAL_ADDRESS
    {
        @Override Object newField()
        {
            return new PostalAddress();
        }
    },
    ...;

    public abstract Object newField();
}
```

Then pass your enum value into the constructor instead of `Class<T>`. No reflection, no large if/else block, and you don't accidentally end up trying to use it with a class you don't support or a type without a public parameterless constructor. The downside is that you don't have compile-time prevention of:

```
new HtmlForm<PersonInfo>(PersistenceHandler.POSTAL_ADDRESS)
```

You could make an *execution-time* check for that, but it would be somewhat messy.

Overall, I'd still go for the first version unless you have a good reason not to.